# Thunderbird 68 (locally installed): getting message count on sidebar

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, ubuntu-dock

I am using locally installed Thunderbird 68 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Traditional question: what is the best means to get number of unread messages displayed in sidebar (Ubuntu Dock)? What piece of software allows just displaying total number of unreads I see when looking at TB?

[Firetray](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) extension doesn't support TB 51+. [Birdtray](https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray) is somewhat glitchy - I'd prefer something more stable, if it exists; also, it requires installing thunderbird from standard repository, which is undesirable.

Comment: Looking for the same solution for KDE...